# Consider a set consisting of matrices and show it is a group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

I am giving $$A=\{1,i,-1,-i\}$$ and $$B=\{\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & \phantom{-}0\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} -1 & \phantom{-}0 \\ \phantom{-}0 & -1\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} \phantom{-}0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0\end{pmatrix}\}$$

- Show that $A$ is a group.
- Make a Cayley table.
- Show that it is cyclic.
- Find all subgroups.
- Find generators for the group and the subgroups.

I have done this for $A$ but how should I do $B$ with matrices?

Comment: You do it the same way; the identity will be the identity matrix, show that the product of any two elements is another element of $B$, each element has an inverse, find a generator, then look at powers of each individual element to find the subgroups - every subgroup of a cyclic group is cyclic.

Comment: When I make the Cayley table should I then just label them?

Comment: That is fine, yes. Just call them $\alpha, \beta,\gamma, \delta$ or something.

Comment: You could also try mapping an element of $A$ to an element of $B$, and showing that the map preserves the group structure of $A$ - this would "transport" the group structure on $A$ to $B$ (this is the basic idea behind representation theory!)